# sqlite3 select always return "1"

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am really new for iOS development. I am using Xcode 10.1

I try to insert then select all the row from database SQLite3 but its always return "1" for every field i call.

this is my code for insert :

```
func insertParameter(id : String, group : String, code : String, name : String, parent1 : String, value1 : String, active : String, count : String){
    let db = openDatabase()
    var insertParamDB : OpaquePointer?

    print(id)

    let insertConfig = "Insert or replace into \(TB_Parameter) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

    if sqlite3_prepare(db, insertConfig, -1, &insertParamDB, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
        print("Error prepare insert param \(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))")
        return
    }else{
        if sqlite3_bind_text(insertParamDB, 1, id, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            print("Error Bind param1 \(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_bind_text(insertParamDB, 2,group, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            print("Error Bind param2 \(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_bind_text(insertParamDB, 3, code, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            print("Error Bind param3 \(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_bind_text(insertParamDB, 4, name, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            print("Error Bind param4 \(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_bind_text(insertParamDB, 5, parent1, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            print("Error Bind param5 \(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_bind_text(insertParamDB, 6, value1, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            print("Error Bind param6 \(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_bind_text(insertParamDB, 7, active, -1, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            print("Error Bind param7 \(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))")
            return
        }

        if sqlite3_step(insertParamDB) != SQLITE_DONE{
            print("Error Insert param \(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))")
            return
        }

        print(count)
        print("Success Insert Param")
        sqlite3_finalize(insertParamDB)
    }
}
```

and this is my code for read

```
func getallParam()->[SelectQuery]{
    let db = openDatabase()

    var dataParam = [SelectQuery]()
    var readParam : OpaquePointer?
    let getAllParam = "Select \(FD_Param_ID),\(FD_Param_Group),\(FD_Param_Code),\(FD_Param_Name),\(FD_Param_Parent1),\(FD_Param_Value1),\(FD_Param_Active) FROM \(TB_Parameter)"

    if sqlite3_prepare(db, getAllParam, -1, &readParam, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        print ("Error Prepare get all param \(String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)))")
    }else{

        var i = 0
        while(sqlite3_step(readParam) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            i = i+1
            print(String(i))
            print(String(cString:sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 0)))

            dataParam.append(SelectQuery(id: String(cString:(sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 0)) == nil ? UnsafePointer<UInt8> ("") : sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 0)),
                                         group: String(cString:(sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 1)) == nil ? UnsafePointer<UInt8> ("") : sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 1)),
                                         code: String(cString:(sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 2)) == nil ? UnsafePointer<UInt8> ("") : sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 2)),
                                         name: String(cString:(sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 3)) == nil ? UnsafePointer<UInt8> ("") : sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 3)),
                                         parent1: String(cString:(sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 4)) == nil ? UnsafePointer<UInt8> ("") : sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 4)),
                                         value1: String(cString:(sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 5)) == nil ? UnsafePointer<UInt8> ("") : sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 5)),
                                         active: String(cString:(sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 6)) == nil ? UnsafePointer<UInt8> ("") : sqlite3_column_text(readParam, 6))))
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(readParam)
    }
    return dataParam
}
```

you can see from my insert code I print the id which I receive from my view controller and its return correctly and I got success insert from my insert code.

and you can see from my read/select code I print the value of column 0 which is the ID but its return "1" and when I print my array not only the id but all field is returned "1"

I learn this code from [sqlite tutorial by ray](https://www.raywenderlich.com/385-sqlite-with-swift-tutorial-getting-started) and [simplified ios](https://www.simplifiedios.net/swift-sqlite-tutorial/).

maybe I miss something but can somebody help me.

Thanks..

Comment: Just an observation,  in no way meant to confuse. `1`  can mean `true`. The ternary operator has a "true/false" flavor. Maybe there's a syntax (read: parenthesis) problem. IME the ternary is `(condition) ? true_val : false_val`. IE I always expect a closing `)` before the `?`

Comment: maybe its true but idk why its returning like that, plus when i insert null, when i read the data it will be return "" ( empty string ).